# Is there any common "onerror" function for ColdFusion 10 REST API?

Tags: api, rest, coldfusion, error-handling, coldfusion-10

I'm using ColdFusion 10 REST API. I want to implement common error handling same as `onerror()` in Application.cfc.

Because, with REST API, if any exception occurs ColdFusion doesn't call the `onerror()` function in Application.cfc file. And I don't want to use `cftry` in each and every REST API function.

Your tips and tricks would be very helpful.